# Issue when both of my state are called (TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble to show to my localhost both of my states (i have the following message : TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined).

Skills.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProgressBar from './ProgressBar';

class Skills extends Component {
  state = {
    programs: [
      { id: 1, value: 'Opera', xp: 5 },
      { id: 2, value: 'Fols', xp: 3 },
      { id: 3, value: 'Micros', xp: 2 },
    ],
    languages: [
      { id: 1, value: 'French', xp: 5 },
      { id: 2, value: 'English', xp: 5 },
      { id: 3, value: 'Spanish', xp: 1 },
    ]
  }

  render() {
    let { programs, languages } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="programsLanguages">
        <ProgressBar
          programs={programs}
          className="programsDisplay"
          title="programs"
        />
        {/* <ProgressBar
          languages={languages}
          title="languages"
          className="languagesDisplay"
        /> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Skills;
```

TO

ProgressBar.js

```
import React from 'react';

const ProgressBar = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={props.className}>
      <h3>{props.title}</h3>
      <div className="years">
        <span>Years of Experience</span>
        <span>1 year</span>
        <span>8 years</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        console.log(props)
        {props.programs.map((item) => {
          let xpYears = 8;
          let progressBar = (item.xp / xpYears) * 100 + '%';
          return (
            <div key={item.id} className="programsList">
              <li>{item.value}</li>
              <div className="progressBar" style={{ width: progressBar }}></div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProgressBar;
```

When i comment

```
{/* <ProgressBar
          languages={languages}
          title="languages"
          className="languagesDisplay"
        /> */}
```

it works. My localHost is showing my object {programs} and same thing if i comment {programs}(my {languages} is showing) but together, it is impossible.

I hope i was enough specific in my exemple.

Thank you very much.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use React Hook**

And pass the same props this way items={progress} OR items={languages}
Like the title and calssName props

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ProgressBar = ({ title, items, className }) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <div className="years">
        <span>Years of Experience</span>
        <span>1 year</span>
        <span>8 years</span>
      </div>
      <div>
       console.log(props)
        {items.map((item) => {
          let xpYears = 8;
          let progressBar = (item.xp / xpYears) * 100 + '%';
          return (
            <div
              key={item.id}
              className="programsList"
            >
              <li>{item.value}</li>
              <div
                className="progressBar"
                style={{ width: progressBar }}
              ></div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const initialPrograms = [
    { id: 1, value: 'Opera', xp: 5 },
    { id: 2, value: 'Fols', xp: 3 },
    { id: 3, value: 'Micros', xp: 2 },
  ],
  initialLanguages = [
    { id: 1, value: 'French', xp: 5 },
    { id: 2, value: 'English', xp: 5 },
    { id: 3, value: 'Spanish', xp: 1 },
  ];

const Skills = () => {
  const [programs, setPrograms] = useState(initialPrograms);
  const [languages, setLanguage] = useState(initialLanguages);
  return (
    <div className="programsLanguages">
      <ProgressBar
        items={programs}
        className="programsDisplay"
        title="programs"
      />
      <ProgressBar
        items={languages}
        title="languages"
        className="languagesDisplay"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Skills;
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you used `languages` as props here

```
<ProgressBar
  languages={languages}
  title="languages"
  className="languagesDisplay"
/>;
```

but you're mapping through `programs` here:

```
{props.programs.map((item) => {
  let xpYears = 8;
  let progressBar = (item.xp / xpYears) * 100 + '%';
  return (
    <div key={item.id} className="programsList">
      <li>{item.value}</li>
      <div className="progressBar" style={{ width: progressBar }}></div>
    </div>
  );
})}
```

also try to check `props.programs` before mapping to have length like this:

```
{props.programs.length && props.programs.map((item) => {
  let xpYears = 8;
  let progressBar = (item.xp / xpYears) * 100 + '%';
  return (
    <div key={item.id} className="programsList">
      <li>{item.value}</li>
      <div className="progressBar" style={{ width: progressBar }}></div>
    </div>
  );
})}
```